# Android Vitals and Stuck Wakelocks?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We have an alert / warning about stuck wake locks in the new Vitals section of the Play Store Developer Console. The apps that have this alert are all audio apps and the offending WakeLock Tag appears to be the AudioMix lock. There is a note about apps that may need long-running locks, such as streaming music, which leads me to believe this warning can be ignored for these particular apps.

I'd like to get some verification on these particular vitals. If these alerts for locks such as AudioMix are a normal thing, can they be safely ignored? Also how are these vital statistics effecting our Play Store rankings, especially if a stuck wake lock for an audio app is considered normal?

Any information about this is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I want to know answer too. If you find it pls share...

Comment: @trizey Did you manage to find any solution? I have the same issue in an Android game probably caused by the music played in the background.

Comment: @MScott I've marked the answer by Neto Marin as accepted. Everyone I've talked to and everything I've read says simply to ignore it, but I was never able to find an answer on rather it influences store rankings or not.

Comment: @trizey thanks for the update! It seems weird that we don't have any official documentation on this specific wake lock.

Comment: @trizey Have you solved this problem? I have a similar one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can safely ignore AudioMix lock if your app is streaming or is a music player (even is local), and it will not impact in your app's ranking or something like this.

According to the support page [Monitor your app's technical performance with Android vitals](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7385505), the issues are excessive wakeups (not a long-running lock), excessive Wi-Fi scans (background), excessive network usage (background) and other similar behaviors.

Comment: Unfortunately the stuck wake locks are issues as well. I have the exact same issue (stuck wake locks) in an Android game, most likely being caused by the AudioMix lock from the music that is being played in the background. Do you happen to know any solution?

Comment: @steliosf Have you fixed this problem? I have a similar one.

Comment: Sorry @ekstro I'm no longer working on that project and I hadn't come to a solution

Comment: @steliosf Ok, thanks a lot for reply!